# In Performance Testing, is this a valid test. need expert opinion.

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner, workload

I am running a 1000 user test. and some of the flows have 25 users with the expected throughput as  0.000011574 per second.

The client is suggesting that I run it with about 1800 second think time.

Using Little's law I am getting the Think Time value to be 2160000.

I am suggesting that we just use 1 user and give a 600 second think time, even though calculations give me 86400 seconds think time. Since the flow has to be tested while under load.

What would be the correct approach? Go with client or Go with my assumption?

Let me know your valuable thoughts.

Comment: Does it really take like 600s to run *one* operation?

Comment: It is not like 600 s to run an operation, it is think time between each iteration of the operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.000011574 of **what** per second?

This reads like a requirement from a server admin and not from "the business."

Comment: Well. it is transactions per second. It is from the business. because they have about 1 transaction once a couple of days.   My question is that is it a valid realistic requirement from business for such a test, or as performance testing expert should I push this back.

Comment: Define "transaction" in this context.  There are about a half a dozen different things that the term "transaction" might refer to, such as "complettion of a business process," "Logins", "hits", "a page request and load of all page components," "a specific page,etc...."    The business will also express this in natural terms, such as incidents per hour or per minute related to the business, but almost unheard of to say per second which is more of a technical metric from platform owners.   Give us total per hour and users of same and pacing becomes easy to calculate